# How to build zstd as a subproject with meson build system

Tags: c++, dependency-management, meson-build, zstd

I want to use [zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) compression library for my C++ library project. My build system is based on [meson](https://mesonbuild.com/). My *meson.build* file looks like this

```
project('foo', 'cpp', default_options : 
    ['cpp_std=c++17', 'buildtype=release'], 
    version : '0.1', license: 'MIT')

subproject('zstd', default_options: 'builddir=build/meson')
```

I made a zstd meson wrap file *subprojects/zstd.wrap*

```
[wrap-file]
directory = zstd-1.4.5

source_url = https://github.com/facebook/zstd/releases/download/v1.4.5/zstd-1.4.5.tar.gz
source_filename = zstd-1.4.5.tar.gz
source_hash = 98e91c7c6bf162bf90e4e70fdbc41a8188b9fa8de5ad840c401198014406ce9e
```

When I run `meson compile` I get this error

```
../meson.build:5:0: ERROR: Subproject exists but has no meson.build file
```

The issue seems to be in the fact that zstd uses CMAKE as a default build system and meson file lives in `build/meson` subfolder, and not in the root where meson expects it. I tried:

- Using `default_options: 'builddir=build/meson'` for the subproject, but that had no effect
- Building zstd using CMAKE integration but failed with other errors and it made the setup more complicated
- Making a patch to move zstd meson build files up two directories to the root of `zstd`, but that required more dependencies and later failed with paths resolution, as zstd expects files in `build/meson` and not in the root.

**Can I easily build zstd as a meson subproject for my C++ library?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option **builddir** in meson, and with **default_options** you can anyway set only that subproject's project options (*zstd/build/meson/meson_options.txt*). Thus, I think, the only way to solve this is to create a patch and it should be rather simple:

1. create *meson.build* in root subprojects' dir
2. move **project(...)** from *zstd/build/meson/meson.build* to this one
3. add **subdir**, so it contains:

   project(...)

   subdir('build')
4. drop one-line meson.build to *zstd/build*

   subdir('meson')

Comment: Right, I was trying to figure this one out, thanks for clarifying. I didn't want to deviate too much from the zstd source code and didn't want to keep track of what is changing upstream (if anything). So I made a patch to an official meson wrap database, hopefully, that can be accepted and I can just use a one-liner `subproject ('zstd')` with a wrap file. Meanwhile, I would just use an older version 1.3.3 available in the database, here's my PR https://github.com/mesonbuild/zstd/pull/4 for the newer version, from what I see someone will have to make a zipped patch manually

Comment: @oleksii thanks, you can try ask this on meson googlegroup where you have better chance to reach authors:  The Meson Build System <mesonbuild@googlegroups.com>. I haven't worked with wraps but from what I've read and found it's not possible to change dir - maybe it's worth feature request. If you do please let me know I'd be interested to know what's better option...